# Who was the first philosopher to make the distinction between slow rational thinking and fast instinctual one?

Tags: history-of-philosophy

Scottish commonsensism seems to have something that resembles the rational/instinctual dichotomy but the concept may go further back to the ancient Greeks.

Comment: Kahneman got the Nobel for his work on Thinking Fast And Slow, where he proved the evidence base for this, so personally I wouldn't go further back than that

Comment: @CriglCragl Certainly it existed much earlier than Kahneman, see for instance this "Peirce held that, in practical affairs, slow and stumbling ratiocination is often dangerously inferior to instinct and traditional sentiment, and that the scientific method is best suited to theoretical research"

Comment: That fails to state that both are useful, & appropriate in different situations.

Comment: If you really want to go back to ancient Greeks see [Plato, the Chariot Allegory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chariot_Allegory). But can following instinct really be called "thinking"?

Comment: @Conifold Sure , why not? Is there any more concise formulation of it after plato esp one that takes into account their relative speeds(intuition being faster than ratiocination)?